# Unable to install new software on Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-neon, fedora-25

Whenever I click 'Install New Software' in the Help menu, I get a popup with

```
An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Clicking 'OK' and selecting 'Neon' or 'Eclipse Update' in the 'Works with' dropdown list gives me another error popup:

```
'Fetching children of Neon' has encountered a problem.
```

I have seen various questions with a similar issue, but none of the answers solve my problem.

I hope to install 'JST Server adapters' to add Tomcat server in Eclipse.

I am using **Eclipse Neon.1** on Fedora 25.

If the 'Install New Software' issue cannot be resolved, is there any way that I can add tomcat server in Eclipse?

Comment: Looks like Eclipse [Bug 331492](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331492).

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded Eclipse Neon.1

I've this version: [eclipse-jee-neon-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz](http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/1/eclipse-jee-neon-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

The following installation will use:

[Tomcat 8.5.15](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.5.15)

[Eclipse Neon.1  Release (4.6.1)  Build id: 20160913-0900](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/1)

[Fedora 25](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/)

in my case, I do not Have any issue when:

I click on `Install New Software`  OR

Selecting `Neon`

To add a tomcat server to Eclipse Neon.1 follow the following steps:

1. download the `tar.gz` file from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.5.15

   direct link:

http://httpd-mirror.frgl.pw/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.15/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz

(extract your files with `tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz` in a Console)

2. Go to File, New, Other, type server, hit next, choose Tomcat 8.5,

Indicate the server location files and hit Finish

[image]
:

3. right click the Tomcat 8.5 server, properties, and click on `Switch Location`

[image]

4. Final step

[image]

in the screenshot follow the red 1, 2, 3 steps:

1. double click on `Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost.server` at left
2. choose: Use Tomcat installation (take control of Tomcat installation)
3. save All

Now start your server under the server tab

And go to localhost:8080 in your browser.

[image]

Now for manager-gui, you have to edit your `tomcat-users.xml` file to edit the different user roles...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already knew how to add server to eclipse. I've done it before on Windows. I'll use the link you provided and see if the server tab shows up.